# What is the true difference between set.seed(n) and set.seed(n+1)

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing, seed

I am trying figure out how the **`set.seed()`** function works in R.

I am curious whether if `set.seed( 3 )` and `set.seed( 4 )` these are more likely to generate duplicate samples than if `set.seed( 3 )` and `set.seed( 100 )`?

**If yes,** how many unique samples a `set.seed( 3 )` can generate, before a match in the samples generated by `set.seed( 4 )` appears?

**If not,** can I conclude that a different **`n`** in `set.seed( n )` does not mean anything as long as they are different?

I heard something related to independent random stream? Is this `n` related to that?

**If yes**, how can I define an independent random stream?
I have already read [What does the integer while setting the seed mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684437/what-does-the-integer-while-setting-the-seed-mean), but it looks does not answer my questions.

Comment: Ouch... this is tough to answer as it depends on the underlying PRNG. Normally you would expect that any 2 seeds are two different PRNG-paths... This would also be enough for two independent streams, if seeded by unique seeds (no matter if 1 and 2 or 1 and 1000)... But in practice seeding is difficult and a pure MersenneTwister implementation might punish you for obtaining independent streams just by using 2 different seeds (while keeping every other param; probably hidden in R, constant). Your questions are also very informal and hard to treat (*generate before match...*) Be more precise!

Comment: This may also be of additional help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86285/random-number-set-seedn-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me also try to give a brief easy answer. I do believe the two comments are useful.

We sometimes need random numbers in our programs. Computer rely on an algorithm to generate random numbers. Because of this, we have the option to re-create the sequence of random numbers generated. This is quite useful in reproducing someones work. In R, if we use

```
sed.seed(42)
runif(5)
```

at any point, it will always give the same sequence of random numbers.

It is not expected that there be a relationship between `set.seed(n)` and `set.seed(n+1)`,  or `set.seed(n1)` and `set.seed(n2)`. Or, it is expected that `set.seed(3)` is not going to generate stream of `set.seed(4)` after a number of iterations, and vice versa.

So, in general, one can treat sequences of random numbers generated by different seeds to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to make any assumptions about the relationship between streams of random numbers that are produced by two different seeds unless the underlying random number generator documents the relationship. For example, I was surprised to learn that the default Mersenne-Twister RNG acts like this:

```
> set.seed(0)
> x <- runif(10)
> set.seed(1)
> y <- runif(10)
> x[2:10] == y[1:9]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I haven't noticed this kind of behavior for any other pair of seed values, but that was enough to scare me away from making assumptions.

If you care about these issues, you should read about the `nextRNGStream` and `nextRNGSubStream` functions in the `parallel` package. These are intended to generate `.Random.seed` values that result in independent streams of random numbers.